Replacement for vintage 3 terminal motor run capacitor
I am looking for a replacement motor run capacitor. In the schematic and parts list, it is a 4.5uF ac capacitor rated to 230v. But, it has three terminals. It is a vintage can package and the terminals are unlabelled except for a red dot on one.
For more context in the circuit, the terminal X is connected to several things, including the power switch, and V and W go to the forward/reverse switches.


Are you asking for us to find a replacement or a design question?

Nearly any electrical supply house can get you a motor run capacitor.  Just take it down to one and show them, ~$20USD.  Also, take some photos of how it was connected so you know how to put the new one in.

It looks like the third terminal "X" is merely a binding post and is not connected internally.  If you cannot find a replacement capacitor with a suitable unconnected terminal, you can substitute some other wire junction method.

could you elaborate on this? Do you mean that I could just join all the wires going into point X, and connect a modern 2-pin capacitor between V and W?

That's exactly what I mean.

Ordered the replacement capacitor, and this worked. Thanks!
